# jQuery ready() and script sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, sequence

I'm an jQuery noob and I'm wondering how fix this issue:

1. I have an external .js script, let's take reflection.js as example.
2. Reflection.js creates canvas reflection for every class="reflect" image.
3. I'm appending a few images trough different JS script that starts when ('document').ready.
4. Of course reflection.js doesn't work for images created by the script above.

How to avoid that?

I guess I'll need callback (?). Unfortunately I'm not getting idea of callbacks idea even after reading documentation.

[edit]

```
<script src="js/reflection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery().ready(function() {   
            jQuery('#thumbs li').each(function(){
                    jQuery('.'+id+' a').append('<img src="' + imgURL + '" class="reflect" /></a>');
                });
            });
 </script>
```

Comment: Both your javascript are executed onDomReady... Just reorder them: first add the images to the DOM and then execute the jqeury reflect plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image loading events do not bubble. You cannot hook into those.

Since your images have the class "reflect" it means you have some control over the source. So I recommend your reflection code publishes an API for you to call.

```
window.Reflect = function(img) {
    ...
};
...
var img = $("<img></img");
img.attr({
   ...
});
Reflect(img);
...
```

If you do not want to do this then you can poll the document for new images.

```
(function poll() {
    var images = $("img.reflect");
    ...
    images.removeClass("reflect")
    setTimeout(poll, 500);
})();
```

Comment: I think you mean "img" instead of "image" :-)

Comment: @Pointy annoying `<img>` tags. Why can't HTML spell!

Comment: I don't think the load event bubbles up for images. See my answer from an older [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043635/live-keyword-not-working-on-load-with-dynamic-html-images/3044115#3044115).

Comment: Don't name your anonymous function! The poll example won't work like this. You mean `(function() {`?

Comment: @Rudie, the function is self-referent. A named anonymous function is a way to avoid arguments.callee, which is depricated.

Comment: @Raynos, can you please tell me how to exactly use your functions with the code I provided? For now they don't work for me.

Comment: @Wordpressor You need to change the source of your reflection library.

Comment: @Raynos, what do you mean by changing source?

Comment: @Wordpressor is "reflection.js" code you wrote or 3rd party code? It's completely dependent on the source of reflection.

Comment: @Raynos, nope, I'm using this script: http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have 2 functions under "ready" sequence and one script depends on other.

The way how I solved this problem, I have build my own includeJS as well as additional ready-checking layer on top of the one which jQuery has.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/templates/js/start-atk4.js

So my code looks like this:

```
$(function(){
   $.atk4.includeJS('reflection.js');
   $.atk4.includeJS('different.js');
   $.atk4(function(){
       $('.reflect').reflection();
   });
});
```

What happens is, after document is ready, jQuery launches above code. It appends 2 scripts and evaluates them (by adding  tag). When evaluation is complete, function atk4.get will execute readiness chain very similar to how jQuery does it.

Comment: there might be some libraries doing similar approach, but if none, feel free to borrow it. :)

Comment: why is agile toolkit _four_ ?